# php set public variable using static method

Tags: php, variables, static

Is there a way to set public var using static method that was called from another class, so that later inside my class Photo I can use it as $this->type?

```
class Photo
{
    public $type;

    public static function create($file, $title, $alt, $type): self
    {
        $photo = new static();
        $photo->file = $file;
        $photo->title = $title;
        $photo->alt = $alt;
        $photo->type = $type; // passed string 'gallery'
        return $photo;
    }

    public function myFunc() {
        echo $this->type; // getting null
    }

}
```

Comment: `new static` is fine. It uses late-static-binding.

Comment: Except for the fact that [there is no OOP](http://axiac.ro/blog/public-properties-are-not-oop/) in the posted code, it looks like it does what you want. How do you use it?

Comment: Ok, then it seems that the problem is the way I use it. Actually, I'm working with Yii2 framework and trying to get this var inside behavior function. I guess, I'll go check how does behaviors work.

Comment: The initialization of instance properties should stay in the class [constructor](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php). The code of function `create()` should be something like `public static function create($file, $title, $alt, $type) { return new static($file, $title, $alt, $type); }`.